# How to manage a huge amount of MapViewAnnotations

Tags: iphone, annotations

I have a MapView with a huge amount of annotations (8000+). The performance is going down by scrolling the map while all annotations are visible. So, I had the idea to hide some annotations when the are in the visible area. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776341/handling-large-quantity-of-mkmapview-annotations/) in the forum, but it doesn't solve my problem.

I tried another solution by writing this piece of code

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSSet *annoSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:[_mapView annotationsInMapRect:_mapView.visibleMapRect]];
    NSMutableSet *annotationsSet = (NSMutableSet *)annoSet;

    NSLog(@"Annos: %i", [annotationsSet count]);

    if([annotationsSet count]>500)
    {
        for(MapViewAnnotation* annotation in annotationsSet)
        {
            [[_mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but after that operation the mapView is near a total breakdown, what can I improve?

Edit:

My new code looks like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSSet *annoSet = [[NSSet alloc] initWithSet:[_mapView annotationsInMapRect:_mapView.visibleMapRect]];
    //NSMutableSet *annotationsSet = (NSMutableSet *)annoSet;

    NSLog(@"Annos: %i", [annoSet count]);

    if([annoSet count]>500)
    {
        for(MapViewAnnotation* annotation in annoSet)
        {
            [[_mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:YES];
        }

    }
    else if([annoSet count] <= 500)
    {
        for(MapViewAnnotation* annotation in annoSet)
        {
            [[_mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setHidden:NO];
        }

    }
}
```

but i dont want to hide all annotations in the visibleRect just a few of them.
Any idea how i can do that in an efficient way?

Comment: I tested my code several times, i'm almost sure that my MapView is not a near breakdown. i thought that way, because i could'nt scroll it. The reason why scrolling was blocked, i tapped too long on an invisible annotation so that the callout bubble came up and in this status it's not possible to scroll the map

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a way to cluster your annotations, which means to display a single annotation where there are several annotations in close proximity. This can get somewhat complicated if you want to do it right, but if you search the Net, you will find several places that discuss clustering strategies and algorithms. I've linked to a number of them below.

[This blog post](http://applidium.com/en/news/too_many_pins_on_your_map/) on the Applidium website discusses one such strategy, and there are now several projects on Github ([mapkit-clusters](https://github.com/j4n0/mapkit-clusters), [kingpin](https://github.com/j4n0/mapkit-clusters), [RevClusterMap](https://github.com/RVLVR/REVClusterMap)) that can take care of clustering for you. If nothing else, take a look at the code and you'll get some idea of how to deal with the problem.

Back when my team was working on the problem, however, we went with a solution described in one of the WWDC videos ([this one](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=111), I think (developer account required)), which we modified somewhat to improve performance.

Note that you will probably have to find a way to let the user know when they click on a clustered annotation. We did this with a custom callout that listed all the annotations represented by that single annotation.

Comment: If you're looking for kingpin you can find it here: http://itsbonczek.github.com/kingpin/